# Can you use subobjects as property values instead of wikipages in semantic mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-web, semantic-mediawiki

I am new to Semantic Mediawiki, which has recently been installed on a wiki I contribute to. I am considering how to represent some of the data, and I thing subobjects might help, but I'm not clear on the details.

In particular, there are a few properties, such as Filming Location for a video (the wiki is for an internet comedy website), that seem a natural fit for the Page datatype, as most of the common locations have a related page, but some one-off locations don't seem worth having a page each. Can you create subobjects of a page that lists all such locations instead, and use those as property values, and if so, how? Also, if so, what does the link point to when you add the value (Using the [[Location::Value]] notation), and what is the text of the link? Are there any downsides to this approach, assuming it works.

To be clear, I would like to miss Locations with pages, and Location that are just subobjects, with Location having the datatype Page.

EDIT: To clarify further, I still want a page for these locations, to provide a brief description, but on a page called [[Minor Locations]], say, which would include a sentence for each of the minor locations (similar to how Wikipedia treats minor characters). My idea is to create the location as a subobject of that page, and the episodes would include the location as a property value, as though they were a page. That way, two episodes could share a minor location, but it wouldn't need a whole article to itself.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the page type, even if you are not going to create all pages. For SMW, it doesn't matter if pages exist or not, they are still valid values for properties.

Answer (score 1):

To add subobjects you must use the `#subobject` parser function, like this:

```
{{#subobject:Location
  |name=Ystad
  |coordinates=55°25′N 13°50′E
}}
```

The advantage of subobjects, as you write, is that you can combine multiple properties without have to create a page.

However, if you don't really need additional properties attached to *every single location*, I would recommend just using pages as values. Nothing prevents you from using the page type, even if you are not going to actually create all pages. For SMW, *it doesn't matter if pages exist or not*, they are still valid values for properties. And querying is going to be much easier that way!

edit: Yes, you can use a SO as a value to a property. They will look something like `Pagename#XXXXXXXX` (see [the official docs](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Subobject_handling#Where_do_subobjects_occur_naturally_in_SMW.3F)), but mixing pages and subobjects as values for the same property is nothing I would personally recommend. Querying will be complicated, and maintenance too...

Comment: I've clarified a bit. This seems to add a subobject as a Location of the page it is included in, but my idea is to define a subobject on a different page ([[Minor Locations]], say), that would include a description of a number of distinct minor locations. (How) could I include that as a Location property value on the episode page?